# Facebook Page Tab App - transfer app to different account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I developed Facebook Page Tab App which has been up and running on my personal Facebook account for about a year now. I need to transfer this (if at all possible) to another Facebook account which is our company account.  Can anyone advise if this is possible and if so where to start?  Also would it cause any disruption to the users currently using the app?
Many thanks

Comment: Define “company account”. Only personal accounts can be developers on the Facebook platform.

Comment: Its a personal account thats used for business

Comment: That’s dangerous, if Facebook finds out, that account might get blocked – and if then that’s the only admin account for an app, you’re in real trouble. I’d advise to leave app control in the hands of the actual persons working for your company (and thereby in their personal accounts). Using admin groups makes it easier to deal with people leaving and new ones joining the dev team.

Comment: Ok, so if I leave the app in my personal account, how can I allow someone else within my team access to it without being able to access my personal messages etc?

Comment: or, could we simply change the personal account for the business to a business account and then transfer the app?

Comment: See my first comment – nope, not possible.

Comment: Why not just add multiple admins? I'm not sure why you're operating on the assumption that only a single user can administer an app

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice but I still want to transfer the app from my personal account to the (business) personal account.  Is this possible?  If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have been told, it's not possible for "business" accounts to create app. I guess you are talking about "fake" personal account to which multiple people from your company will have access to. If that's the case, then just add that account as admin to your app - and then remove yourself from admins. That's it - app belongs to another account now.

**UPDATE**: probably "fake account" is not the best word. I should have said "company owner will register personal account which will be used for business purposes". In this case you can transfer the app there.

Comment: _“app belongs to another account now”_ … and will belong to “no one” any more once FB finds out that the account is fake and blocks it. (And then good look trying to get it unblocked, because for that FB requires you to send personal ID documents that confirm that it’s not a fake, that is the account name has to match the name in the ID documents.)

Comment: well, in our case our "business" page was created by company owner so I kinda see where topicstarter is coming from.

Comment: I’m just saying that using a _fake_ account for developing can get you into much trouble. As already said, adding groups is the best option IMHO.